# How to let hidden line be displayed as dash style in pst-solides3d

Tags: pstricks

I want to draw a tetrahedron and an arrow, and part of the arrow is inside of the tetrahedron. However, I'd like the inside part is displayed as dash line. How to do that?

My code does not work.

```
\psset{unit=1}
\psset{lightsrc=10 -20 50,viewpoint=50 -20 30 rtp2xyz, Decran=50}
 \begin{pspicture}(-7,-4)(7,7)
 \psSolid[object=new, fillcolor=gray,linewidth=0.01, sommets=
-1 -1 -1   1 0 0   0 1 0   0 0 1,
faces={
[0 2 1] [2 3 1] [2 0 3] [3 0 1]},
    action=draw
]
\psSolid[object=vecteur,
    args = 2 2 2,
    linewidth=0.02,
    linecolor=blue](-1,-1,-1)
\end{pspicture}
```

Does any other software realize this effect?

Comment: Your code works, I haven't had a problem... But the vector is still not dashed.

I tried with the option `fusion`, but now it doesn't compile...

Maybe It's due to the newSolide you defined. I tried with another newSolide, but the fusion just don't work...